# isolate IP cameras in separate network using a 2nd NIC on my windows machine

Tags: windows, security, ip-camera

I have blue iris running on a windows machine. Atm, my Ip cameras are all on my network. I want to isolate them in a separate network. Was thinking adding a 2nd NIC on my windows machine, connect all IP cameras on a separate switch and connecting the switch to the second NIC of the windows machine.

this will prevent the IP cameras having access to my main network right? Questions:

Should I use a different subnet on the second NIC and IP cameras or can I keep the same subnet?
I have set static IPs on all my IP cameras with the gateway with the IP of my current router.. What gateway should I put now?
What are the security risks/attacks to my windows machine if someone disconnects one of my IP camera and connect his laptop on the rj45 cable?

Comment: If your router supports VLAN, it might be better for isolation.

Comment: I know but no I don't have a management switch nor a router with vlan

Answer (score 1):

You can install a second NIC on your Windows machine, and use it to communicate directly with the camera subnet. You should use a different subnet for the cameras and your regular LAN. If you don't want to change the cameras, change your LAN subnet.

Do not configure a gateway on the second NIC, or any of the cameras (which means you'll probably have go to all the cameras anyways). With no gateway, and no routing tables, the only traffic that should be successfully passed around is local subnet traffic. Your computer will access the internet and everything else through the first NIC, which has your gateway configured. Here is an example configuration.

```
NIC1 (LAN/Internet):
IP: 192.168.1.1 (can be DHCP)
SM: 255.255.255.0
GW: 192.168.1.254 (whatever your router IP is)
DNS: Your preferred DNS 


NIC2 (Cameras): 
IP: 192.168.2.1 (static)
SM: 255.255.255.0
GW: Not Configured
DNS: Not Configured
```

Since the cameras can only access any other network through your PC, you can use the Windows Firewall on your PC to block everything on NIC2 except for the service you whitelist (outbound access to a camera).

If your switch that is connected to the cameras has MAC address filtering, you can cause a port to automatically shutdown if it detects a MAC address that is not a camera, which can help the physical access problem. If you have given up physical access to a live port on your local network, there's maybe not much you can passively do to protect yourself from attacks. Use the firewall on your PC to prevent inbound communications on NIC2, and secure physical access to the cameras.

Comment: ok I can configure the cameras with no gateway. In an event my windows machine goes down, I guess I can't simply connect the switch on which all my IP cameras are connected to the main LAN.. it won't work right as the IP cameras are on different subnet with no gateway.
Now, if an intruder manage to disconnect one of my camera and connects his laptop. If he puts a fixed IP same subnet as my main secured network with the gateway of my router, will he be able to access my main network??

Comment: If the only access to your main network from the camera network is through this PC, you need to ensure that PC is secured. If you are this concerned about security and intruders, then you should use a real network firewall to segregate the networks, and not a PC. If you must use the PC, you should ensure the Windows firewall settings are as strict as possible on your camera subnet and NIC. Any sufficiently motivated intruder is going to be able attack your network from a variety of angles, especially if you have given up physical access. You can just make it as difficult as possible.